# Change fancybox2 background color

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to change the background color of fancybox2 from black to blue, but I can't as sometimes I can change it but the popup becomes transparent as well, and some other it just doesn't work.

This is what I've tried so far:

Option 1: (not changing the color)

```
 beforeShow: function() {
                $(".fancybox-overlay").css({
                    "backgroundColor": '#FFFFFF',
                    "backgroundImage": 'none' // optional if you prefer a solid color
                });
            },
```

Option 2:

```
helpers : {
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.4,
            css : {
                'background-color' : '#1E72B2'
            }
        }
    }
```

I saw now it uses a background image, the only way should be to create a new background image?

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks! Guillermo.

Comment: Why on earth did I get a -1?!!! Is there any way to check why? Is a technical question!!!!

Comment: JFK, I tried your solutions but didn't work. What I ended up doing is changing the fancybox_overlay.png which is used by fancybox2 for the overlay. Of course I kept the transparency of it.
Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFK, I tried your solutions but didn't work. What I ended up doing is changing the fancybox_overlay.png which is used by fancybox2 for the overlay. Of course I kept the transparency of it. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** : (works fine)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    beforeShow: function() {
        $(".fancybox-overlay").css({
            "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "backgroundImage": 'none' // optional if you prefer a solid color
        });
    }
});​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/awQTW/)** as in your example

**EDIT** : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/awQTW/1/)** updated to match blue color

**Option 2** : (works fine too)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            opacity: 0.4, // this make the color transparent. set to 1 for solid color
            css: {
                'background': '#1E72B2'
            }
        }
    }
});​
```

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PwgNk/)**

... so not idea what you are doing wrong but here there is something you could check :

- check you syntax (copy/paste from demos to compare)
- make sure you have a proper `DOCTYPE` in your document
- make sure you are loading all the files (check paths) specially the fancybox css file (the sprite image should be on the same directory as the css file)
- load a single instance of jQuery first and then the rest of js files
- make sure you custom scripts are inside the `.ready()` method like :

  ```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
  });
  ```